# What are some ways to derive $\left( \boldsymbol{E}\cdot \boldsymbol{E} \right) \nabla =\frac{1}{2}\nabla \boldsymbol{E}^2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

For each of the two reference books the constant equations are as follows:
$$
\boldsymbol{E}\times \left( \nabla \times \boldsymbol{E} \right) =-\left( \boldsymbol{E}\cdot \nabla \right) \boldsymbol{E}+\frac{1}{2}\nabla \boldsymbol{E}^2
$$

$$
\boldsymbol{E}\times \left( \nabla \times \boldsymbol{E} \right) =-\left( \boldsymbol{E}\cdot \nabla \right) \boldsymbol{E}+\left( \boldsymbol{E}\cdot \boldsymbol{E} \right) \nabla 
$$
We can reason about the terms that correspond to the same in both equations.
$$
\left( \boldsymbol{E}\cdot \boldsymbol{E} \right) \nabla =\frac{1}{2}\nabla \boldsymbol{E}^2
$$
What are some ways to reason about the above equation to arrive at it? (I would like to have access to a variety of reasoning options)

Comment: Is this a maths question?

Comment: I think it's a physics problem that I came across in an electrodynamics book.@MariusLadegårdMeyer, If there's a mistake I'll post it to the math community

Comment: could you add the reference? It looks like you're mixing vectors and operators (like $|\mathbf{E}|^2 \nabla$. This is an operator, since you need to ask what is nabla acting on?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second equation with its $({\bf E}\cdot {\bf E})\nabla$ isnot really correct as the nabla has to act on one of the ${\bf E}$'s. The correct form is best written as  $({\bf E} \cdot \nabla {\bf E})$ with the dot understood being a product between the two ${\bf E}$'s and not a scalar product with the $\nabla$. There is no standard  vector notation  way of saying  this, but  I've  put the parentheses where I have to   distinguish it from $({\bf E}\cdot 
\nabla) {\bf E}$. In components, however, the $j$-th component of the term is
$$
({\bf E} \cdot \nabla {\bf E})_j \stackrel{\rm def}{=}  E_i \partial_j E_i = \frac 12 \partial_j (E_i E_i), 
$$
where a sum on the "$i$" index is understood.

Comment: I am used to the notation $(\nabla \circ \vec A)_{ij} = \partial_i A_j$.

Comment: @Sebastian Reese  Where did you find that notation? It's not one I know.

Comment: It was commonly used in the physics lecture at my university (in Germany; I think I've also seen it in some German books but I can't find an example right now). It was used in general as the "dyadic product", as in $A = A_{ij} \vec e_i \circ \vec e_j$.